# How to space out text annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have the following data

```
     index   trk  rbegin  rend      suffix  prefix    id
    0     STWOS  130.30  129.00    NaN      H        1
    1   missing  129.00  128.00    NaN      H        1
    2     STWOS  128.00  125.61    NaN      H        1
    3   missing  125.61  125.00    NaN      H        1
     4      STWS  125.00  121.37    NaN      H        1
    5     STWOS  121.37  114.50    NaN      H        1
    6     DTWOS  114.50  106.84    NaN      H        1
   7     STWOS  106.84  101.50    NaN      H        1
  8      STWS  101.50   98.57    NaN      H        1
 9     STWOS   98.57   92.18    NaN      H        1
 10     STWS   92.18   90.25    NaN      H        1
 11    STWOS   90.25   86.00    NaN      H        1
 12    DTWOS   86.00   81.00    NaN      H        1
13    STWOS   81.00   78.59    NaN      H        1
 14     STWS   78.59   75.07    NaN      H        1
 15    STWOS   75.07   69.71    NaN      H        1
  16     STWS   69.71   67.78    NaN      H        1
   17    STWOS   67.78   60.60    NaN      H        1
    18     STWS   60.60   58.00    NaN      H       1
   19    STWOS   58.00   55.40    NaN      H        1
    20     STWS   55.40   53.31    NaN      H        1
    21    STWOS   53.31   47.96    NaN      H        1
    22     STWS   47.96   45.00    NaN      H        1
    23    STWOS   45.00   43.05    NaN      H        1
    24     STWS   43.05   40.29    NaN      H        1
```

Basically I am trying to create a graph. It is a bunch of vertical from the rbegin to rend. If the trk is STWOS it is just a black line from rbegin to rend. If the trck is missing it is a black dashed line. if the trk is dtwos it is two parallel black lines.

I am trying to get a graph which annotates the beginning and end of each tracks.

And get something like this

[image]

But instead I get something like this

[image]

It is like toward the end of the top of my graph. All of my annotations get mumbled up together. And I am not sure how to spread them out and what to do in matplotlib.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes as ax


def drawVline(ax, r, x, l, c, ls='solid'):
    ax.vlines(x, r[3], r[4], lw=l, color=c, ls=ls)
def drawHline(ax, r, l, c):
    ax.axhline(y=r[3], xmin=0.50, xmax=0.54, lw=l, color=c)
    ax.axhline(y=r[4], xmin=0.50, xmax=0.54, lw=l, color=c)    
def annot(ax,r):
   ax.annotate(str(r[3]),(0.37,r[3]), fontsize=20)
   ax.annotate(str(r[4]),(0.37,r[4]), fontsize=20)



df1=pd.read_csv("line3.csv")
egs=df1["line_id"]
egs=df1["line_id"]
b=1
df1=df1[df1["line_id"]==b]
df1=df1.drop(["Unnamed: 0","index"],axis=1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,20))
x1=.5
x2=.47
x3=.54


for idx,row in df1.iterrows():
    ax.set_title("line:"+str(b))
    if row[0]=="STWOS":
        annot(ax,row)
        drawVline(ax,row,x1,2,"k")
    if row[0]=="DTWOS":
        annot(ax,row)
        drawVline(ax,row,x1,2,"k")
        drawVline(ax,row,x2,2,"k")
    if row[0]=="DTWS":
        anno2(ax,row)
        drawVline(ax, row, x1, 2, 'k')
        drawVline(ax, row, x3, 1, 'r')
        drawHline(ax, row, 1/4, 'r')
    if row[0]=="missing":
        annot(ax, row)
        drawVline(ax, row, x1, 2, 'k', ls='dashed')  
    if row[0]=="STWS":
        annot(ax, row)
        drawVline(ax, row, x3, 1, 'r')
        drawHline(ax, row, 1/2, 'r')
        drawVline(ax, row, x1, 2, 'k')       
ax.axis(xmin=0, xmax=1)
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
#ax.set_ylim(40,130)
ax.grid(color='0.9', lw=0.5, ls='dashed')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This seems like the same question you posted previously.

Comment: Its similar I am just having now an issue with annotations that I cannot figure it out

Comment: Like 130.3 is so close to 129.0 I dont know if there is a way to make them a bit less jammed

Comment: The easiest ways would be 1) reduce the size of the text or 2) increase the vertical dimension of the figure size.